# inventory_stock_1 doest exist on Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, inventory, index

When I go to product pages and checkout the exception shows:

```
Exception #0 (Zend_Db_Statement_Exception): SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'inventory_stock_1' doesn't exist, query was: INSERT INTO `search_tmp_5c4f24124efa61_76233970` SELECT `main_select`.`entity_id`, SUM(score) AS `relevance` FROM (SELECT DISTINCT  `search_index`.`entity_id`, (((0) + (0)) * 1) AS `score` FROM `catalog_product_index_eav` AS `search_index`
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity` AS `product` ON product.entity_id = search_index.entity_id
 INNER JOIN `inventory_stock_1` AS `stock_index` ON stock_index.sku = product.sku
 INNER JOIN `catalog_category_product_index_store1` AS `category_ids_index` ON search_index.entity_id = category_ids_index.product_id AND category_ids_index.store_id = '1' WHERE (search_index.store_id = '1') AND (`search_index`.`attribute_id` = 102 AND `search_index`.`value` in ('2', '4') AND `search_index`.`store_id` = '1') AND (category_ids_index.category_id = 394)) AS `main_select` GROUP BY `entity_id` ORDER BY `relevance` DESC, `entity_id` DESC
 LIMIT 10000
Exception #1 (PDOException): SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'inventory_stock_1' doesn't exist
```

Does anyone meet that problem on Magento 2.3?

Comment: check your schema , it might be a problem with `SQL SECURITY INVOKER`

Comment: any solution? Facing similar issue after migrating to new server.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I got the solution for this, you need to create a view table `inventory_stock_1` for your catalog in database.

Here is the command you need to run in your DB SQL. Make sure to update 3 things in below query `dbusername, localhost, dbname`.

```
CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`dbusername`@`localhost` SQL SECURITY INVOKER VIEW `inventory_stock_1`  AS  select distinct `legacy_stock_status`.`product_id` AS `product_id`,`legacy_stock_status`.`website_id` AS `website_id`,`legacy_stock_status`.`stock_id` AS `stock_id`,`legacy_stock_status`.`qty` AS `quantity`,`legacy_stock_status`.`stock_status` AS `is_salable`,`product`.`sku` AS `sku` from (`dbname`.`cataloginventory_stock_status` `legacy_stock_status` join `dbname`.`catalog_product_entity` `product` on((`legacy_stock_status`.`product_id` = `product`.`entity_id`)));
```

Comment: my issues similar your reply. It was caused by username mysql incorrect between local and host. Thank.

Answer (score 31):

You need elevated permissions to use the `CREATE ALGORITHM` bit

This can and will stop an import in it's tracks.

Instead use this statement to create the view

```
CREATE
OR REPLACE
VIEW `inventory_stock_1` AS select
    distinct `legacy_stock_status`.`product_id` AS `product_id`,
    `legacy_stock_status`.`website_id` AS `website_id`,
    `legacy_stock_status`.`stock_id` AS `stock_id`,
    `legacy_stock_status`.`qty` AS `quantity`,
    `legacy_stock_status`.`stock_status` AS `is_salable`,
    `product`.`sku` AS `sku`
from
    ( `cataloginventory_stock_status` `legacy_stock_status`
join `catalog_product_entity` `product` on
        (( `legacy_stock_status`.`product_id` = `product`.`entity_id` )));
```

Comment: This one is the perfect solution as defining a name can cause a permission issue.

Answer (score 3):

Find data patches name from `patch_list` table

> Magento\InventoryCatalog\Setup\Patch\Schema\CreateLegacyStockStatusView

Delete or rename it.

run upgrade command

> php bin/magento s:upg

This issue may be raised when you export or import the database incorrect way.

you can found this query at here.

> vendor\magento\module-inventory-catalog\Setup\Patch\Schema\CreateLegacyStockStatusView.php

Thank you to my senior to help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks again!

Comment: This is probably the cleanest solution i've seen for this problem!

Answer (score 1):

I have same bug. Seems becouse not imported full SQL of DB.

Seems the reason in Magento2 backup tool (have been imported Magento backup to new Database).

**How to fix.**

Open dump SQL file - 
Lookking on row with - **DROP VIEW IF EXISTS `inventory_stock_1`;**

Before words **CREATE ALGORITHM** symbols for breaking like **\n**

But MySQL not understands this symbols correcty, and returned Error.

Just remove breaking symbols,
and save dump SQL.

And try upload.

[image]

Comment: Exactly my case. I exported via Magento Backup tool. Got syntax error when importing that backup sql file. There was a \n which caused syntax error. Deleting and moving CREATE ALGORITHM... to new line worked.

Answer (score 0):

Don't import the database directly.

Open it in your favorite editor then search by inventory_stock_1.

Define username before `@`localhost

Now import database.

This time inventory_stock_1 table will be there.

Answer (score 0):

look on

```
\nCREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED SQL SECURITY INVOKER VIEW `inventory_stock_1`
```

and remove **\n**

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Magento 2.4.x

Download inventory_stock_1 from database, open it with an editor and

replace

```
CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`user`@`localhost` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW
```

with

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW
```

- Save the file.sql
- drop the view from the database
- import the saved .sql file
- reindex

Answer (score 0):

i am having the same error but when i add the above query "CREATE
OR REPLACE
VIEW `inventory_stock_1` AS select
distinct `legacy_stock_status`.`product_id` AS `product_id`,
`legacy_stock_status`.`website_id` AS `website_id`,
`legacy_stock_status`.`stock_id` AS `stock_id`,
`legacy_stock_status`.`qty` AS `quantity`,
`legacy_stock_status`.`stock_status` AS `is_salable`,
`product`.`sku` AS `sku`
from
( `cataloginventory_stock_status` `legacy_stock_status`
join `catalog_product_entity` `product` on
(( `legacy_stock_status`.`product_id` = `product`.`entity_id` )));"

i get the following error `#1932 - Table 'magento2.cataloginventory_stock_status' doesn't exist in engine`

Answer (score -1):

The view is not created if it exists because of the "typo", resulting in a follow-up error.

The problem with the "newline" character in de SQL-code is caused by the Magento tool to create a database backup (bin/magento setup:backup).

If you create the backup file using mysqldmp you won't have this problem, but in that case, the SQL-code tries to create a TABLE rather than a VIEW. This then also results in an error on the inventory_stock_1 view.

In both cases you need to correct the lines in the SQL-file.

Answer (score -2):

This works for me -
I had 6 stores in magento , so I go to **`admin -> inventory->stocks`** and created **`6 new entries for 6 stores`**.
After that I reindex data and it works.